# What is meaning when someone say "Xай"?

Tags: перевод

What is meaning this word? Same as "privet"? And what should i reply for this word?

Comment: please, provide some context. Under what circumstances have you encountered this word?

Comment: I am voting to close this because it is not about Russian language.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's the same as "привет" because "Хай" is simply a transliteration of "Hi". You can use "privet/привет"(more informal) or "Zdravstvyite/здравствуйте" (more formal).

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 8):

`Хай` (transliteration of `Hi`) is more informal and joyous than `привет`, which is in turn more informal than `здравствуй(те)`.

`Хай` is seldom used in on-line chats (use `привет` or `hi`).  In real life talks, it may be used between young people.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context, could be "hi" (mainly the same way as if someone says "bonjour" or "hola" to an English-speaking audience) but also "speaking ill" or "running down" - [«Гражданочка, не поднимайте хай!»](http://song5.ru/text/%D1%8F%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%88-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)